# "@Model.Score" is diplayed in the Related sidebar here on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, related-questions

The text "@Model.Score" is being displayed in each entry of the Related sidebar.

[image: @Model.Score]

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it...

Comment: So many to blame but [who is the winner today](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pushing out a fix. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sklivvz It's *always* Sklivvz ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - only because he is doing Localization.

Comment: They hired me for my skill at apologizing!

Comment: Ya dropped yer razor